# mysql subtract multiple tables NOT working properly

Tags: mysql

I tried to subtract values ​​from several tables but the results were not correct.

```
SELECT SUM(t1.pay_1) - SUM(t2.pay_2) as trx FROM
(
SELECT SUM(payment) AS pay_1
FROM tr_order
WHERE date = '".$date."' 
AND agent='".$arr[$y]['name']."'

UNION ALL

SELECT SUM(nominal) AS pay_1
FROM transaction
WHERE date = '".$date."'
AND to_agent='".$arr[$y]['name']."') AS t1,                                                                               

(SELECT SUM(nominal) AS pay_2
FROM transaction
WHERE date = '".$date."'
AND from_agent='".$arr[$y]['name']."') AS t2
```

the result of t1.pay_1 is 350000 and the result of t2.pay_2 is 0

but the result of t1.pay_1 - t2.pay_2 is 0

whats' wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's 0 and not null? and is transaction an empty table?

Comment: oh yes, transaction is empty table, so What should I do?

Comment: Coalesce and read my answer.

Comment: oh oke, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there the sub query t2 or t1 returns null then the main query will return null, you should always code for this using coalesce. Since t1 potentially returns 2 rows then you should sum pay_1 before calculating trx to avoid the implicit cross join doubling up. A simplified version of your model and query illustrates

```
drop table if exists t,t1;
create table t(payment int);
create table t1(nominal int, to_agent int, from_agent int);

insert into t values (10),(10);

select 
        payone,
        sum(pay_2) pay2,
        payone - sum(pay_2) pay1_pay2,
        coalesce(payone,0) - sum(coalesce(pay_2,0)) as trx
from
(
select sum(pay_1) payone from
(
select sum(payment) pay_1 from t
union all
select sum(nominal) pay_1 from t1 where to_agent = 1
) s
) a
,
(select sum(nominal) pay_2 from t1 where from_agent = 1) b;

 +------+------+-----------+------+
| pay1 | pay2 | pay1_pay2 | trx  |
+------+------+-----------+------+
|   20 | NULL |      NULL |   20 |
+------+------+-----------+------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: thank you very much sir,

i just put coalesce in my query like this:

SELECT COALESCE(pay_1,0) - coalesce(pay_2,0) as trx FROM.......

and it's work 100%.

thank you very much